# I can't connect to my server with parse sdk

Tags: javascript, parse-server

i can't reach my parse server, i tried a lot of things but i have found no way to make it works. So if anyone has an idea.. thanks a lot

```
  Parse.initialize("***", "***"); //PASTE HERE YOUR Back4App APPLICATION ID AND YOUR JavaScript KEY
Parse.serverURL = "***";
  function Connexion(){
    var user = new Parse.User();
    user.save({
      username: 'sampeusername',
      email: 'sample@email.com',
      password: '123456'
    }, {
      success: function(response) {
        alert('New object create with success! ObjectId: ' + response.id + `, ` + user.get('username'));
      },
      error: function(response, error) {
        alert('Error: ' + error.message);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: You want to save a user on the front end side ? or create an account and login ?

Answer (score 0):

With the user object I think you don't want to save, but you want to signup

```
var user = new Parse.User();
user.set("username", "sampeusername");
user.set("password", "sample@email.com");
user.signUp({
  success: function(response) {
    alert('Account created');
  },
  error: function(response, error) {
    alert('Error: ' + error.message);
  }
});
```

If you want to save a user that is not yours you have to use your MasterKey